# Kendo UI Numeric Textbox - Max Value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, kendo-ui

I'm using the Kendo UI Numeric Textbox. I have a max value set on the text box. However, I want the max value to work more like max-char attribute.

Currently, if I type in anything past 99999, say 111111, it reverts to max value (99999), I would rather the textbox just prevent additional numbers than to revert to 9999.

```
  @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox<double>()
                .Name("XXXX")
                .Max(99999)
                .Min(1)
                .Format("\\#")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style="width:100%"})
            )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the maxLength attribute of the input. So, on page load, do the following:

```
$("#XXXX").attr('maxlength','5');
```

Edit based on comments :
In order to apply rule to all numeric boxes, the following should work:

```
$("input[data-role='numerictextbox']").attr('maxlength','5');
```

Comment: This would work, the only issue is I have like 20 text-boxes on this page, and other pages similar to this that will require the same thing. If it were a one of, this may work, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution.  Thanks,

Comment: how about the following that captures all numeric text-boxes? $("div[data-role='numerictextbox']").attr('maxlength','5');

Comment: I have edited the answer based on the comment. Could you please accept as answer if it helped. Thanks!